# Radion button does not work properly in React

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to create reusable radio button in React. But I have met several problems which I dont know how to solve. When I click the radio button, it changes only after two clicks. When I want to console.log(value from state) it works unproperly as well. What I do wrong?

parent component is below

```
 <h2>Radio</h2>
      <div className={'radio-content'}>
        <div><Radio label={'tea'} value={'tea'} name={'drinks'} defaultValue={true} /></div>
        <div><Radio label={'coffee'} value={'coffee'} name={'drinks'} /></div>
        <div><Radio label={'juice'} value={'juice'} name={'drinks'} /></div>
      </div>
```

Radio button component

```
interface IProps {
  color?: 'primary' | 'success' | 'secondary' | 'danger' | 'warning' | 'info' | 'dark';
  name?: string;
  className?: string;
  style?: React.CSSProperties;
  label?: string;
  value?: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  checked?: boolean;
  onChange?: (event:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  required?: boolean;
  defaultValue?: string
}

type DefaultProps = Partial<IProps>;

const defaultProps: DefaultProps = {
  color: 'primary',
  disabled: false,
  label: '',
};

const Radio = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, IProps>((props,ref) => {

  const {label, color, className, checked, disabled, value, name, defaultValue, ...nextProps} = props;

  const [isSelected, setSelected] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (defaultValue) {
      setSelected(true);
    }
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (event:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (event.target.value===value) {
      setSelected(!isSelected);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <label
        className={classNames(
          className,
          'radio',
          `radio-${color}`
        )}
      >
        <input
          {...nextProps}
          type="radio"
          name={name}
          value={value}
          checked={isSelected}
          onChange={handleChange}
          disabled={disabled}
          ref={ref}
        />
        <span>{label}</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
});

Radio.defaultProps = defaultProps;
Radio.displayName = 'Radio';

export default Radio;
```

Comment: Hi Ivan and wellcome to Stakc overfolow. In order to do this right and the component to be reusable you do not need to store the selected = true/false within the component. This should be controlled by the Radio component consumator. This means the checked prop should be used whether the radio is checked or not.

Comment: You mean, I dont need useState in my component? Can I control it through parent component?

Comment: Yes - take a look at how the material UI have implemented it : https://mui.com/material-ui/react-radio-button/#standalone-radio-buttons . The component that uses the Radio controls whether it is selected or not, and it listens for the onChangeEvent on the Radio component